# How to get not used value from ip range and assign to field in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core project I have method which is checking ip. If it exists it will throw exception ip is existing. I am also checking valid range. For ex: I have 10.19.0.1/22 and range is 10.19.0.1-10.19.3.254
I am checking my ipAddress for that. Is it possible somehow also check range but assign value from this range but not duplicated value. For ex: 10.9.0.2 assign by default if it exist assign 10.9.0.3 in this range.

My method looks like:

```
        [HttpPost("create")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVm(VirtualMachine vm)
        {
            if (await _repo.VmExists(vm.Name))
                return BadRequest("VM name already exists");

            if (await _repo.NetworkExists(vm.IpAddress))
                return BadRequest("IpAddress already in use");

            if (await _repo.GatewayExists(vm.IpAddress))
                return BadRequest("IpAddress already in use");

            vm.Hypervisor = _context.Hypervisors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HypervisorId == 
            vm.HypervisorId);
            vm.Project = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ProjectId);
            vm.Management = _context.Managements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ManagementId);
            vm.Status = VMStatus.Pending;

            if (vm.Management != null)
            {
                var range = IPNetwork.Parse(vm.Management.Name);
                var firstUsable = range.FirstUsable.ToString();
                var lastUsable = range.LastUsable.ToString();
                var broadcast = IPAddressRange.Parse($"{firstUsable} - {lastUsable}");
                var interval = broadcast.Contains(IPAddress.Parse(vm.IpAddress));

                if (interval)
                {
                    await _context.VirtualMachines.AddAsync(vm);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Ok($"{firstUsable}-{lastUsable}");
                }

                return BadRequest("Please specify valid ip range");
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: If you are using a vendor app for DNS management, it might be best to use their API to get next available unassigned IP address. If you dont have that, a method to start pinging IPs from start till the one that doesnt would suffice (It will take a long time to get the next IP this way)

Comment: Plus not all active IPs respond to a ping, so you're still at risk of an address conflict.

Answer (score 0):

> [...]checking valid range.

If you are familiar with subnetting you can use it to check if an IP(-Rang) `A` is a subset of another IP-Range `B`. Take the subnet mask to calculate the resulting start address for both IP-Ranges. If those addresses do match `A` is a subset of `B`.
In your case `B` might be `10.19.0.1/22` and `A` might be `10.19.0.2`. Take the subnet mask of `B (255.255.252.0)` and use the logical *and operation*:

```
B  10.19.0.1           00001010.00010011.00000000.00000001
 & 255.255.252.0 = 22  11111111.11111111.11111100.00000000
----------------------------------------------------------
b  10.19.0.1           00001010.00010011.00000000.00000001

A  10.19.0.2           00001010.00010011.00000000.00000010 
 & 255.255.252.0 = 22  11111111.11111111.11111100.00000000
----------------------------------------------------------
a 10.19.0.1            00001010.00010011.00000000.00000000
```

Since `a == b` it follows that `A` is a subset of `B`!

*Beware*: In you example above `10.9.0.2` is **not** part of `10.19.0.1/22`.

---

> Is it possible [...][to] assign value from [...] range but not duplicated value.

Pinging is not the best option for various reasons e.g. the server might not respond to ICMP requests. Since I don't know your exact environment I cannot give you a profound advice.